# What does a truncated distribution mean?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, truncation, fortran

I am a little bit confused about  truncated distributions such as truncated normal distribution. I have a code in FORTRAN where the function `gen_rnorm(mean,sigma)` returns random normal value. Now I want to write a code for  truncated normal distribution with $a=-3$ and $b=3$. My question is does truncated normal distribution mean that I run the function `gen_rnorm(mean,sigma)` and check if the returned value is between $a$ and $b$. If not then ask for another value. Is this what truncated normal distribution means?.

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: It is simply the normal density function defined by its mean and variance cut off to be 0 below -3 and above 3 in your case.  But it is renormalized to integrate to 1 over the intervaal [-3, 3].

Comment: Your function generates a random number on that interval based on the derived density.  One way to d it is to sample from the original normal distribution rejecting values outside the interval..

Comment: @MichaelChernick, Are you saying that I should run my function and only accept values between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197628/laymans-explanation-of-censoring-in-survival-analysis/198481#198481

Comment: That is called rejection sampling it is one of the ways to generate the samples; The method does work by sampling and rejecting values outside the range and continuing to sampling until you get the required sample size.